# Issues in List view Retrieve from MYSQL Database

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

My issue is when i am running the application unfortunately app has stopped error occurred can any one give solution to this.Fatal exception occurred in main What is this error.please help me to fin out this solution?

```
 public class JSONPrser extends ListActivity
{


/**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,this.populate()));
    }

    private ArrayList<String> populate() {
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://something.com/webservices/categories.php");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();
            // gets the server json data
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String next;
            while ((next = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(next);

                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                    items.add(jo.getString("category name"));
                }
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime:




  FATAL EXCEPTION: main


             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{anilkumar.com.yoursub/anilkumar.com.yoursub.JSONPrser}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
                                                 at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:254)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
                                                 at anilkumar.com.yoursub.JSONPrser.onCreate(JSONPrser.java:31)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4466)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Xml code

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="anilkumar.com.yoursub.MainActivity">
<ListView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/list"/>
```

Comment: please post xml code too.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your layout(xml) in layout you need to change id to **android.R.id.list**